# Assign dataframes in a list to a list of names; pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a variable

```
var=[name1,name2]
```

I have a dataframe also in a list

```
df= [df1, df2]
```

How do i assign df1 to name1 and df2 to name2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, assuming the lengths of both lists are the same you just iterate over the indices of both lists and just assign them, example:

```
In [412]:
name1,name2 = None,None
var=[name1,name2]
df1, df2 = 1,2
df= [df1, df2]
​
for x in range(len(var)):
    var[x] = df[x]
var

Out[412]:
[1, 2]
```

If your variable list is storing strings then I would not make variables from those strings (see [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)) and instead create a dict:

```
In [414]:
var=['name1','name2']
df1, df2 = 1,2
df= [df1, df2]
d = dict(zip(var,df))
d

Out[414]:
{'name1': 1, 'name2': 2}
```

Comment: The var=['name1','name2'] contains strings. do we still iterate over the lists. Apologies for not including the string earlier and also the df1= m *n matrix

Comment: Sorry you want to make variables from a string name? Also my code just demonstrates how to iterate over 2 lists and overwrite the contents of one list with another

Comment: Also I suggest you use a dict to achieve what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python

Comment: When you say `m*n matrix` what does this mean, is this an array?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can do this by:

```
for i in zip(var, df):
     globals()[i[0]] = i[1]
```

And then access your variables. 
But proceeding this way is **bad**. You're like launching a dog in your global environment. It's better to keep control about what you handle, keep your dataframe in a list or dictionary.